# Recently earned right to set bounties, but older questions do not have links

Tags: bug, bounties

I recently earned the Bounty achievement and I am keen to apply a bounty to a question that has affected me, [Hibernate LazyInitializationException on find() with EAGER @ElementCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604370)

However, when I go to the section below the comments area, all I see is a link that says "question eligible for bounty Jul 24 at 22:06".

The link brings me to the docs on setting bounties, but I cannot set a bounty - despite meeting all the criteria I can see.

Is there something extra I have to do to enable bounties or is this a bug with SO?

Comment: Do you have any userscripts running? I noticed one of mine was breaking bounty setting recently. (I really should track that down)

Comment: I have [WasteNoTime](http://bumblebeesystems.dyndns.org/wastenotime/) and [AdBlock](http://safariadblock.com) for Safari. Disabling Extensions doesn't do anything (except let the ads through).

Comment: Works for me (TM). Cache?

Comment: but Bobby, you haven't just earned the right to add bounties ;-) My questions were created before I had the achievement.

Comment: Are you still seeing this eligibility statement on the question?

Comment: no, because somebody answered it without the bounty :-)

Comment: actually, Jarrod, it does say "start a bounty" now, but there is no need because I've marked it as answered.